# Routing Error uninitialized constant ConfessionController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I`ve been using Rails for one month, and I made a new website but already I have error:

```
Routing Error uninitialized constant ConfessionController
```

This is my controller:

```
def destroy
    @confession = Confession.find(params[:id])
    @confession.destroy

    redirect_to delete_confession_path
  end
```

This is my index.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', home_path(confession), method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

This are my routes:

```
delete '/confession/:id' , to: 'confession#destroy' , as: 'delete_confession'
```

I don't understand how can I solve this problem.

Comment: What is your controller class name?

Answer (score 0):

By convention you must have a controller named confessions_controller (plurar) in the controller folder and inside the class named

controllers/confessions_controller.rb

```
class ConfessionsController < ApplicationController 
end
```

yor routes

```
delete '/confession/:id' , to: 'confessions#destroy' , as: 'delete_confession'
```

and your index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', delete_confession_path(confession), method: :delete,
          data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Comment: It was already confessions controller and it was in this shape  class ConfessionsController < ApplicationController 
end. which means that it was plural. There is not incorrect anything. I applied changing things and I took again error message. Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/confession/13".